# Remove drawers from a vanity

Tags: cabinets, vanity

I have a vanity.  I need to replace the faucet.

[image]

I cannot for the life of me get the drawers to come out.

Most have a little latch or you pull up and out, but I see no way to remove them.  I can't access the faucet without at least two drawers out.

Any ideas?

*P.S.
These are small and I can hardly get my hands in between the drawers.*

EDIT: More pics
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would try pulling up(or down) lightly when pulling and they are almost all the way out.

Comment: Look under the drawer near the front. Often there is a small lever that can be pushed in or out to release the drawer.

Comment: agree with RMDman there is sometimes a little locking pin which slides from the slide into the drawer and locks the slide onto the drawer and you have to back this out to be able to remove the drawer from the slide ( typically on both sides at the front of the drawer )

Comment: Also, sometimes the drawers just drop onto pins attached to the front of the rails.  Show us a pic of the bottom of a drawer looking up at one of the front corners where the front of the rail is.

Comment: I tried your suggestions.  Nothing.  I added more pics, if that helps.  All the little things sticking out in the pics don't more.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No luck with all the suggestion.  I decided to unscrew the draw to remove it.  Maybe that was the answer all along